# activeadmin heroku style sheet config issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [activeadmin heroku stylesheet config issue with partial fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933514/activeadmin-heroku-stylesheet-config-issue-with-partial-fix)

I'm having a heroku issue with active admin gem. I get the following issue after checking the logs.

```
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: active_admin/mixins.
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Load paths:
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)):
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>FbApis</title>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss:2
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2765708727675805011_44722120'
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-15T03:23:29+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including:

```
gem 'sass'
```

You might try

```
gem 'sass-rails'
```

And see if that helps...